# Does the .NET SerialPort class (C#) behave differently on older systems?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a relatively short C# program that feeds data over an RS232 port using the following format:

'STX' Header 'Checksum' 'ETX'

'STX' data1 'Checksum' 'ETX'

'STX' ... 'Checksum' 'ETX'

'STX' dataN 'Checksum' 'ETB'

The receiving end is supposed to reply with either an ACK or NAK byte upon receiving the ETX/ETB.

This works fine running on computers with Windows 7 64 bit.

However there was a problem getting the program to start on a Win XP 32 machine, because I had built the program to target .NET version 4.5 (which apparently isn't supported by that version of Win XP).

I changed it to target .NET version 4 instead and now the program starts just fine. But the receiving end doesn't respond with ACK or NAKs anymore, only the first time (upon sending the datafile header).
I printed out the byte buffer on the console and at the place where the ETX byte is supposed to be there is an UP DOWN ARROW WITH BASE symbol (↨) which tells me it somehow didn't send an ETX at all.

What's weird about this is that it works fine on windows 7 machines, and the first transmission (header) returns an ACK just like it's supposed to, but when the first data packet is sent no more replies... no ACK or NAK.

Comment: There's nothing weird about `SerialPort` being buggy. It's known to do many tricks on different platforms. Check out connect.microsoft.com to see which bugs were potentially fixed from 4->4.5 upgrade(obviously something was, if win7 behaviour has changed on framework switch). Also, fire up your serialport debugger and see what is going on. `I printed out the byte buffer on the console` is not debugging :P

Comment: The ↨ glyph is displayed in the console for ASCII code 23.  Which is the ETB control character.  So that's not your problem.  Having subtle timing bugs in code that uses SerialPort is *very* common, ignoring the return value of Read() is a standard bug.  Not implementing an event handler for the ErrorReceived event is another.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa I know I didn't have time to get started on debugging last Friday but I will start first thing Monday. So with SerialPort being kind of dodgy, what is the recommended way of going about doing serial communication today? A third party library perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone run into similar problems; my problem was that I used a USB to serial converter. It caused the timings to become all messed up. What I did to solve it was to subscribe to the `SerialPort`'s `DataReceived` Event, and then grab the data inside the event handler with `serialport.ReadExisting()` (which also clears the receive buffer). So the thread would roughly do:

Send data -> *wait for DataReceive to fire* -> handle data -> repeat.

Just be sure to put a timeout in the waiting loop.

Comment: Have similar problem that serial port buffer behaves little differently under x64 and x32 Windows 7.